# Using CodeLite IDE for OpenCV in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ide, codelite

I can compile a sample C++ Code (including OpenCV) using both CMake and following command line:

> g++ cv.cpp -o cvapp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

But I want to use *CodeLite IDE* for this purpose. I have added

> /usr/include/opencv;/usr/include/opencv2

in the **Include Paths** under **compiler** tab in project settings. And added

> /usr/local/lib

in **Libraries Search Path** under **Linker** tab.

But still, I am getting errors shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUdCK.jpg) for a sample code. 
Now is it possible to use CodeLite for OpenCV coding environment? If yes then how?

Comment: Your answer solved the issue and saved my day! @eyllanesc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use opencv in codelite the simplest option is to continue using pkg-config, you can do this as follows:

1. Right click on the project name and select `settings...`

[image]

2.Open the following dialog and select the Linker tab, in that window add `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` in linker-options:

[image]

Press the apply button and Ok and then compile the project.

Comment: Worked like charm!